# python:How do I improve this code(TicTacToe)?

Tags: python

I have just started learning python, this is a code for a TicTacToe game. 
Can you please suggest any improvements? Also how can I alert the player if same symbol is entered in consequent inputs(without using a variable)?

```
pos_matrix=[[' ',' ',' '],[' ',' ',' '],[' ',' ',' ']]
def my_tictactoe(pos,symbol):
    if pos_matrix[pos[0]-1][pos[1]-1]!=' ':
        print('Invalid input')
        exit
    else:
        pos_matrix[pos[0]-1][pos[1]-1]=symbol
    for i in range(0,3):
        print(pos_matrix[i][0]+' | '+pos_matrix[i][1]+' | '+pos_matrix[i][2])
        print('--|---|--')

    if is_win():
        print('GAME OVER. \n Player with symbol {x} wins!'.format(x=pos_matrix[pos[0]-1][pos[1]-1]))
        for i in [0,1,2]:
            pos_matrix[i][0]=pos_matrix[i][1]=pos_matrix[i][2]=' '


def is_win():
    for i in [0,1,2]:
        if pos_matrix[i][0]==pos_matrix[i][1]==pos_matrix[i][2]!=' ':
            return True
        elif pos_matrix[0][i]==pos_matrix[1][i]==pos_matrix[2][i]!=' ':
            return True
    if pos_matrix[0][0]==pos_matrix[1][1]==pos_matrix[2][2]!=' ':
        return True
    elif pos_matrix[0][2]==pos_matrix[1][1]==pos_matrix[2][0]!=' ':
        return True
    else:
        return False


my_tictactoe((1,1),'o')
my_tictactoe((2,2),'x')
my_tictactoe((3,2),'o')
my_tictactoe((1,3),'x')
my_tictactoe((2,1),'o')
my_tictactoe((3,3),'x')
my_tictactoe((3,1),'o')
my_tictactoe((1,2),'x')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can omit the player inputting his symbol all together. 
Players take turns, so you can advance a simple counter of turns and use the appropriate symbol:

```
pos_matrix=[]
player = 'xoxoxoxox'
turn = 0

def initGame():
    global pos_matrix
    global turn
    turn = 0
    pos_matrix=[[' ',' ',' '],[' ',' ',' '],[' ',' ',' ']]

def printGame():
    for i in range(3):
        print("{} | {} | {}".format(*pos_matrix[i])) # decompose into its 3 values
        print('--|---|--')
    print("")


def my_tictactoe(pos):
    global turn
    global player

    if pos_matrix[pos[0]-1][pos[1]-1] != ' ':
        print('Invalid input')
        exit(1) # return fail code
    else:
        pos_matrix[pos[0]-1][pos[1]-1]= player[turn] 

    printGame()

    if is_win():
        print('GAME OVER. \n Player with symbol {x} wins!'.format( x = player[turn] ))
        initGame()
    elif turn == 8:
        print('Game Over -  D R A W.')
        initGame()

    else:
        turn += 1


def is_win():
    for i in [0,1,2]:
        if pos_matrix[i][0]==pos_matrix[i][1]==pos_matrix[i][2]!=' ':
            return True
        elif pos_matrix[0][i]==pos_matrix[1][i]==pos_matrix[2][i]!=' ':
            return True
    if pos_matrix[0][0]==pos_matrix[1][1]==pos_matrix[2][2]!=' ':
        return True
    elif pos_matrix[0][2]==pos_matrix[1][1]==pos_matrix[2][0]!=' ':
        return True
    else:
        return False


initGame()
my_tictactoe((1,1))
my_tictactoe((2,1))
my_tictactoe((1,2))
my_tictactoe((2,2))
my_tictactoe((2,3))
my_tictactoe((1,3))
my_tictactoe((3,1))
my_tictactoe((3,2))
my_tictactoe((3,3))
```

For code enhancement, start creating smaller functions that have one exact purpose (see the `printBoard()` ) until every function has only [one reason to change](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) - read about the other S**OLID** as well - they also help to get to cleaner code.

---

Edit: Added DRAW-State and initGame()